Do I have to request approval from Microsoft whenever I release a codebase change in an MSTeams App?
If I'd have an MS Teams App that was published through the Partner Center, do I need to notify Microsoft about any change I do to my app? For example, if I add a new card activity response or if I add new capabilities to existing ones?
What will happen if I don't do that, will Microsoft immediately remove my app when they detect it during periodic checks? Will it make my account be in a "bad standing"?
When do they do periodic checks?
If my changes are only on the backend, do I need to make sure that users using an older version of the app will still have the same old behavior? Or can I enable an approved change to everyone, regardless of the app version?

Changes to a published MS Teams App via Partner Center require approval. Non-compliance may lead to app removal and 'bad standing.' Periodic checks are undisclosed. Backend changes should maintain old version compatibility. Always consult the latest Microsoft guidelines.

For more details, please refer this documentation link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/appsource/publish

@Dinesh-MSFT Thanks for the response.
